# How is BRDF usually implemented?

Tags: reflection, graphics, render, raytracing, pbr

I have a small path tracer, and I am trying to figure out how to implement some basic BRDFs.
Here's a brief description of the pipeline I use (without recursion):

```
1) For each pixel:
   1.1) For each sample:
      1.1.1) I construct a path.
      1.1.2) I calculate the contribution of this path.
      1.1.3) I calculate the "probability" of this path.
      1.1.4) Finally, I calculate the overall color value(taking into account number of samples, "probability" and contribution of the path).
   1.2) Take the sum of all samples' values and write it to the pixel.
```

So, I calculate the direction of reflected rays in the step `1.1.1) I construct a path`.

For now, I have implemented diffuse reflection, specular reflection, glossy reflection, refraction.
Now I want to implement a complex BRDF, let's say Cook-Torrance BRDF.
I see that it contains several components (diffuse reflection and specular reflection). How should I trace these rays to get the combination? Should I choose between diffuse_ray/specular_ray randomly and then accumulate the values(multiplied by some coefficients) as usual?(like, if a random value is more than 0.5 then I trace a diffuse ray, otherwise - specular) Or should I trace multiple rays from each intersection?

How is it usually implemented in physically-based renderers?

P.S. If somebody knows some good articles on this topic I would be glad to see them. I tried to read pbrt but it seems very complex and huge to me. And some things there are implemented differently, like the camera model and other stuff.

Comment: in my stochastic tracer I spawn separate rays for specular and diffuse reflection, but the method you outlined above keeps the ray tree smaller and should reduce computation complexity.  I have considered using that method but I couldn't figure out how to have "colour" random coefficients so that the split between diffuse and specular could vary based on surface colour (as I believe happens with plastic vs metal materials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step might be to let your BRDF decide how the ray should bounce. If it's a combination of multiple methods, assign a probability in the BRDF to each method, and then have the BRDF pick one according to the given probabilities.

For example, suppose you want a BRDF that's a combination of specular and diffuse reflection. When you instantiate the BRDF, you might tell it that you want 60% specular and 40% diffuse. Then, when your path tracer queries the BRDF to get the reflected ray direction, the BRDF can internally calculate a specular ray 60% of the time and a diffuse ray 40% of the time.

EDIT - another, perhaps more accurate approach would be to have the BRDF use the provided probabilities to generate a reflected direction by interpolating between the two methods. In our example above, when queried, the BRDF calculates a specular ray and a diffuse ray for every intersection, and returns a new ray whose direction is a linear interpolation of 60% of the calculated specular ray and 40% of the calculated diffuse ray.